# C# Data Table Rows value is empty string, but there is Null value

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datatable, null

The value of dt.Rows.Count always equals 1, and the value of dt.Rows[0][0] and dt.Rows[0][ 1] is empty string when I query sqlStr of no records.

But I execute sqlStr in database. It's null. [Here is the database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mzgN.png)
I don't know why it is.

```
string sqlStr = "select SUM(userIncome),SUM(userSpend) from tb_billlist where userPhone = '" + userPhone + "' and " +
     "billTime between '" + beginDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'";
//execute sql
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = MysqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(sqlStr);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
{
    userBillInfo.userAllIncome = (float.Parse)(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString());
    userBillInfo.userAllSpend = (float.Parse)(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString());
}
else
{
    userBillInfo.userAllIncome = 0;
    userBillInfo.userAllSpend = 0;
}
```

Comment: that looks like there were no rows..

Comment: I would *start* by fixing the SQL injection attack vulnerability (or conversion fragility, at the very least) you've got going there. Use parameterized SQL, *always*.

Comment: You will always get a row, since SUM() always returns something.

Comment: @Marko Juvančič If SUM() is no data, will it always return empty string? Could you help me explain to me more specifically? thanks：)

Comment: @BugFinder it returns rows of empty string value.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I don't understand clearly. Would you mind show some examples to me! thanks very much!^—^

Comment: No, searching for information about SQL injection attacks and parameterized SQL should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Calling `.ToString()` on `DBNull.Value` results in the empty string, but that MASSIVE sql injection hole is your first problem. From the looks of things, that `MysqlHelper` is fundamentally flawed such that it practically forces you to write vulnerable code.

Comment: @Jon Skeet okay and thanks^_^

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I understand why there is empty string, thank you^_^ I will check my MysqlHelper method and try to write stronger code(๑•ᴗ•๑)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To achieve this goal you can change your query, and if case of 'sum of nulls', the return value is 0:

```
string sqlStr = "select COALESCE(SUM(userIncome), 0), COALESCE(SUM(userSpend), 0) from tb_billlist where userPhone = '" + userPhone + "' and " +
     "billTime between '" + beginDate + "' and '" + endDate + "'";
//execute sql
...
```

Thus, you would have 0 as the return value for the fields.

Comment: Thanks^_^ It works! and I find IFNULL also works the same as COALESCE in mysql.